# Vim Windows creating temporary files

Tags: swap-file, backup

I am using Vim on windows. Any time I edited a file, Vim is created temporary files. When I created a file,

```
    mysql-build-properties.xml
```

Vim is creating files like these:

```
    mysql-build-properties.xml~
    mysql-build-properties.xml~~
```

Are these files Vim temporary files? If so, how do to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

I think these are the vim backup files.

This should turn them off:

```
set nobackup
```

There will still be one while vim is actually writing the file (e.g, during the `:w` command; use `set nowritebackup` to disable).

There is also a swap file, another temporary file. That exists only when vim is running; its purpose is to recover unsaved changes if e.g., vim crashes. To disable this as well, `set noswapfile`. You can also put these in a different directory via the `directory` setting.